# How to input multiple log groups for cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

so I have a cloud formation stack, a bit modified version of this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer-elasticsearch-kibana-dashboards/?adbsc=startups_20150803_50195176&adbid=628221613226332160&adbpl=tw&adbpr=168826960 stack by AWS. The problem is that I want to stream multiple log groups to ES and kibana.

I thought the logical solution would be to change Type: String to Type: CommaDelimitedList :

```
    "LogGroupName": {
  "Description": "The CloudWatch Logs log group to use as the source for the subscription that feeds the Elasticsearch cluster",
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": ""
},
```

But that gives me an error that the LogGroupName type must be a string. Why doesn't this method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS, there isn't support for this feature yet :

https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer/issues/18#issuecomment-246456407